# Creating a module: form config class invalid?

Tags: 8, forms

I currently have a working module that parses iCal links to events. This part is working. What I am trying to do now is creating a configuration page for my module that allows me to input the link to this iCal file.

I have followed multiple guides and always seem to end at the same spot:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\google_calendar\Form\GoogleCalendarConfigForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of /home/vagrant/Sites/gordon/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php).
```

I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this. I can see in my form file that I have named it GoogleCalendarConfigForm. It's in the /modules/google-calendar/Form folder. What part am I missing?

Comment: Actually, it's because my /Form/ directory needed to be in /src/, not in the main module directory. There are some tutorials online that are missing this aspect. All figured out.

Comment: Its pretty much laid out here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8 - everything goes in `/src` of a module at given namespaces.